# FFMPEG out put on azure blob

Tags: azure, ffmpeg, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

we are developing app which takes up the input file from the azure blob storage and does the requried action and needs to put back the video file to blob storage. Its worker role

Please find the below which i have written, its work fine on local machine, and this is basically worker role solution. challenges we have is on out put path. Input path i am giving the blob http url and its converting and placing on my local system. if i want to upload same in azure how can i do that

```
        string mpegpath = @"C:\ffmpeg\bin";
        string input = @"http URL of blob storage";
        string outputFile = @"D:\Shared\100.mp4";
        string Params = string.Format(" -ss 00:00:09 -i {0} -t 00:00:23 -vcodec copy -     acodec copy -y {1}", input, outputFile);
       string ffmpegPath = Path.Combine(mpegpath, "ffmpeg.exe");
       string ffmpegParams =  Params;

        Process ffmpeg = new Process();
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k " + ffmpegPath + " " + ffmpegParams;
        ffmpeg.Start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put all the tools you need into a blob storage container and then in the startup of the worker role just sync everything from this container to the c:\ drive and you can run your code.

Using the WindowsAzure.Storage

Comment: What i understood is deploy the worker role in the VM, attache that VM with additional space of 100GB and place the content in that

Comment: I would use cloud services (Worker Roles if no website is needed). You could add some extra storage if you need.